# Returning true or false in a SQL function

Tags: sql, oracle

I am studying network administration (I won't specialise in programming so related things are tough for me) and I have a problem with a function in SQL. I use Oracle SQL Developer and I have to create a function with tells if a patient has an appointment on a specific day or not. The table needed is that (some things are in Spanish, since my teacher wants us to write some things in SP, but they can be easily understood):

```
        create table citas(

        id_cita number(10),

        fecha_cita date ,

        hora_cita varchar2(5),

        nombre_consulta varchar2(40),

        id_paciente number(8),

        CONSTRAINT citac_pk PRIMARY KEY (id_cita),
```

And the function code I am creating is something like that

```
       CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION fun_tiene_cita (id_paciente number, fecha_cita date) 
       return number is

       begin

       if (exists(select id_paciente from citas where id_paciente = 500 and fecha_cita = 03/03/2020)) 
       then
       return 'true';
       else
       return 'false';
       end if;
       END fun_tiene_cita;
```

Obviously, it isn't working, so, what could I do? I've tried everything I know but I can't solve it.

Comment: The function is declared as returning a number, but you are returning a string.  Return 1 or 0, otherwise change return type to a varchar type.

Comment: People who are responding with answers, PLEASE direct the newbie away from using STRINGS for everything.  See RamblinRose comment and sers answer.

Comment: That's so accurate. The problem is I am not understanding codes with strings and things a newbie like me wouldn't understand :( Anyway, I'm trying with varchar2 type and still getting errors, I don't understand what should I do

Comment: What’s this `exists` operator?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `COUNT` aggregate function to check the existence of the record and return the `true` or `false` as follows:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION FUN_TIENE_CITA (
    P_ID_PACIENTE NUMBER,
    P_FECHA_CITA DATE
) RETURN VARCHAR2 IS
    P_RESULT   VARCHAR2(5);
BEGIN
    SELECT
        CASE
            WHEN COUNT(1) > 0 THEN 'true'
            ELSE 'false'
        END
    INTO P_RESULT
    FROM CITAS
   WHERE ID_PACIENTE = P_ID_PACIENTE 
     AND FECHA_CITA = P_FECHA_CITA ;

RETURN P_RESULT;

END FUN_TIENE_CITA;
/
```

Cheers!!

Comment: The hard-coded values need to be variables to accept values from the IN parameters. And function can return boolean.

Comment: Ok, Done!! Please check

Comment: `WHERE ID_PACIENTE = ID_PACIENTE` is like 1=1 always true, edit the variable name. Perhaps it's a typo!

Comment: Yeap... Haven't seen that column names are the same as the parameter names.

Comment: I would like to thank you all for your responses! However, the only code that has worked for me is this one! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You should return varchar2

```
   CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION fun_tiene_cita (id_paciente number, fecha_cita date) 
   return varchar2 is

   begin

       if (exists(select id_paciente from citas where id_paciente = 500 and fecha_cita = to_date('03/03/2020'))) 
       then
          return 'true';
       else
         return 'false';
       end if;
   END;
```

Comment: you and the op need to to_date the March 3, 2020 or it will always return false

Comment: Thanks for your fast responses! I perfectly understand what you both have said, but now sql developer keeps showing me 2 errors: (5,8) pl/sql: statement ignored and (5,12) PLS 00204 - exists can only be used wthin a sql statement. Do you have any idea why does this happen?

Comment: `BOOLEAN` is a PL/SQL only data type; you cannot use it in SQL statements (including as the return value of a function you are going to use in an SQL statement).

Comment: Thanks! I have just tried that option, now edited, but it still gives me the same 2 errors :(

Comment: `to_date('03/03/2020')` without the format mask makes no sense. Not everyone will have same locale-specific NLS settings as yours. It will throw `ORA-01821: date format not recognized`.

Comment: Or consider using an ANSI date literal: `date '2020-03-03'`

Comment: Please do not direct a newbie to use strings.... 0/1 is better oracle option than strings.............overcoming the oracle does not (or did not have) true booleans when I last used it.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need an `IF`, `EXISTS(...)` yields a boolean, which is exactly what you need:

---

```
create table citas(
       id_cita integer
        , fecha_cita date
        , hora_cita varchar
        , nombre_consulta varchar
        , id_paciente integer
        , CONSTRAINT citac_pk PRIMARY KEY (id_cita)
        );

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION fun_tiene_cita (IN id_paciente integer, IN fecha_cita date)
   RETURNS boolean AS
$func$
        SELECT exists(select * from citas c
         where c.id_paciente = $1 and c.fecha_cita = $2
        ) ;
$func$
language sql stable;
        ;

        -- test it ...
SELECT fun_tiene_cita(1, '2020-01-01'::date)
        ;
```

---

Note: this is Postgresql - syntax. Oracle might use slightly different syntax. I don't know, for instance, how Oracle exactly handles function arguments.

Comment: Thanks for your fas response! I perfectly understand what you say, but now sql developer keeps showing me 2 errors: (5,8) pl/sql: statement ignored and (5,12) PLS 00204 - exists can only be used wthin a sql statement. Do you have any idea why does this happen? It's the same error as i have just explained above to the other users :(

Comment: Maybe Oracle has different function semantics. I'll delete my answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to select a row into a variable and catch any exceptions if the row isn't found (or if too many rows are found):

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION fun_tiene_cita (
  i_id_paciente IN citas.id_paciente%TYPE,
  i_fecha_cita  IN citas.fecha_cita%TYPE
) RETURN VARCHAR2
IS
  p_id citas.id_paciente%TYPE;
BEGIN
  SELECT id_paciente
  INTO   p_id
  FROM   citas
  WHERE  id_paciente = i_id_paciente
  AND    fecha_cita  = i_fecha_cita;

  RETURN 'true';
EXCEPTION
  WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND THEN
    RETURN 'false';
  WHEN TOO_MANY_ROWS THEN
    RETURN 'true';
END;
/
```

Answer (score 0):

PL/SQL has a boolean datatype - why not use this:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION fun_tiene_cita (id_paciente number, fecha_cita date) 
   return boolean is

begin

   if (exists(select id_paciente from citas where id_paciente = 500 and fecha_cita = 03/03/2020)) 
   then
   return true;
   else
   return false;
   end if;
END fun_tiene_cita;
```

Only caveat: you can't call a function like this from SQL - only PL/SQL.

Oh, and regarding a good comment below this pseudo-code could be abbreviated like this:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION fun_tiene_cita (id_paciente number, fecha_cita date) 
   return boolean is
begin
   return (exists(select id_paciente from citas where id_paciente = 500 and fecha_cita = 03/03/2020)) 
END fun_tiene_cita;
```

Comment: Upvote for directing the newbie to a NON string answer.   Here is my addition:      Please consider using correct datatypes, and try not to push everything to a string.  Unfortunately, Oracle does not have a dedicated boolean datatype like most other RDBMS do......BUT consider using 0/1 as described here : https://www.oratable.com/boolean-datatype-in-oracle/                  If that has changed in later versions of Oracle, please respond to my comment with documentation, not "slams".  Thanks.

Comment: Thanks! Anyway, I keep getting the errors i have described in other comments, statement ignored in (5,4) and exists can only be used within a sql statement (5,8). I suppose I'm using pl/sql since I'm using begin and all those things. I'm not sure I have to use booleans because my teacher didn't mention it.

Comment: Sorry, @Paco3196, I did only correct the data-type. For the other problems please refer to the solutions offered  ... :-)

Comment: Why not just `return exists(...)`